# How to make an universal postcode mask for ngx-mask input?

Tags: angular, masking, ngx-mask

I use ngx-mask 14.2.4. I want to allow the following conditions for my postcode input field:

- between 2 and 12 signs
- allow letters, numbers and '-'. Also allow spaces but not after '-'.

I tried:

```
<input
  type="text"
  [mask]="mask"
  [patterns]="customPatterns"
  [specialCharacters]="['-']"
  [showMaskTyped]="true"
  [dropSpecialCharacters]="false"/>
```

and

```
this.mask = '0{12}';
  this.customPatterns = { '0': { pattern: new RegExp('\[A-Za-z0-9- \]')} };
```

But it didn't work. It doesn't let me input the special characters (space and -). How to achieve the goal?

Comment: Maybe you need to escape the special characters with a " \ "?

Comment: Did any of the current answers resolve your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the special characters.

Escape => `\s` or `\`

"-" => `\-`

"\" => `\\`

Regular expressions are pretty tricky at first sight, I usually use [this cheatsheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet) when I need to create some.

Answer (score 0):

Change your input tag in Html like this ,

```html
[specialCharacters]="['-', ' ']" <!-- Added space -->
```

And change your **ts** file like this,

```js
 mask = 'A{2,12}'; // Adjust the pattern to allow between 2 and 12 characters
  customPatterns = { A: { pattern: new RegExp('[A-Za-z0-9- ]') } }; // Allow letters, numbers, hyphens, and spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.mask = '0{12}';
this.customPatterns = { '0': { pattern: new RegExp('\[A-Za-z0-9\-\s\]')} };
```

Although I suspect you'll need to escape the backslashes because the regex is embedded in a string in javascript. So, try this, too:

```
 this.customPatterns = { '0': { pattern: new RegExp('\[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\s\]')} };
```

Note that the space and the hyphen are included "literally" by `escaping` them (reference here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html)

Also, you probably mean this:

```
 this.mask = '0{11}';
```

because thats 12 digits, when you include the first 0 in the count.